# How to develop around Google API in GWT hosted mode?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-api

I've been developing a GWT project which uses Google APIs authorized by the App Identity API. This way, I can authorize my application backend to exploit the APIs needing authorization (e.g. Calendar, Mail, etc). I want to keep control of the data, I don't want users to need their authorization for the personal data.

It is very useful to use the hosted mode to develop GWT apps. But as far as I know, you won’t be able to hit the real calendar API using OAuth while running in hosted mode because the GAE dev server doesn’t simulate the Application Identity API.

But how about the other APIs? Has anyone used this approach? Can I simply create a mock for the Identity API and work with Calendar Java API in hosted mode?

It is unclear to me how to work around this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a Calendar Stub class.

In case you are running in the production environment,
the Stub class calls the Google API using the App Identity API.

In case you are running in the developer environment,
the Stub class calls a secret handler in your production app,
which then calls the Google API using the App Identity API.

All you basically need to create is a proxy handler in your production app.
You can have a shared secret between the dev and the prod environment
and use https to communicate.

Comment: That is my last resort... is this the way to go? It is not an easy task to stub google APIs.